# Why do I find different values for the same complex integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

We have

\begin{align}
\mathcal{J}=\int_{\partial \mathcal{D}(0,2)} \dfrac{2}{z^2+1}dz.
\end{align}

Using the Cauchy Theorem we can write
\begin{align}
\int\dfrac{2}{(z-i)(z+i)}dz
\end{align}
we have 2 simple poles.

For the first pole, $z=-i$ write
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\Phi(z)}{(z+i)^1} \mapsto \mathrm{Res}(f)=\dfrac{\Phi^{(0)}(-i)}{(1-1)!} = \dfrac{2}{-2i}=i
\end{align}
and the second, $z=i$,
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\Phi(z)}{(z-i)^1} \mapsto \mathrm{Res}(f)=\dfrac{\Phi^{(0)}(i)}{(1-1)!} = \dfrac{2}{2i}=-i
\end{align}
and by the residue theorem
\begin{align}
\mathcal{J} = 2\pi i \sum (\text{residues)} = 2\pi i(i-i)=0.
\end{align}

However, going for the direct parameterization,
\begin{align}
\gamma(t) = 2e^{it}, t \in [0,2\pi]\\
\gamma'(t) = 2i e^{it}
\end{align}
then we have
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{4ie^{it}}{4e^{2it}+1}dt = \ldots = [2\arctan(2e^{it})]_{0}^{2\pi} = \dfrac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}
where did I go wrong?

Comment: Wow. That's criminal misconduct on my part and on the part of the maker of a well known integral calculator.

Since I was short on patience and time I directly computed the integral and this is the result it gave me.

Please verify yourself by using the link here https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=%5Cdfrac%7B4ie%5E%7Bit%7D%7D%7B4e%5E%7B2it%7D%2B1%7D&intvar=t&lbound=0&ubound=2%5Cpi

Comment: What is the definition of $\arctan z$ for complex $z$ ? Especially for $|z|\ge 1.$ I would transform the function into $${ie^{-it}\over 1+{1\over 4}e^{-2it}}$$ and then it is possible to make use of $\arctan.$ Although there is another way: expand into the geometric series $\sum a_n e^{-(2n+1)it}$ and the integral of each term is $0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I know what you say but for this one I used a calculator that gave me wrong number and I was too tired to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dirty trick showing that the integral is indeed equal $0.$ We have $$\int\limits_{|z|=2}{2\over z^2+1}\,dz=\int\limits_{|z|=r}{2\over z^2+1}\,dz,\quad r>1$$ Next $$\left | \int\limits_{|z|=r}{2\over z^2+1}\,dz\right | \le {4\pi r\over r^2-1}\underset{r\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$$